# MySQL password not resetting even after re-installation on Ubuntu

Tags: mysql, ubuntu-16.04, mysql-python, mysql-5.7

I forgot my Mysql Root password.I have uninstalled Mysql using the following commands-

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge mysql*
sudo apt-get autoremove
sudo apt-get autoclean
```

After uninstalling MySQL I ran the following command to verify if MySQL was uninstalled properly-

```
dpkg --get-selections | grep mysql
```

Then I executed the following command to install MySQL-

```
sudo apt-get install mysql-server
```

I didn't get any message to set root password.
After Executing the following command it ask's for root password which i haven't set.

```
mysql -u root -p
```

Please help.

Comment: Maybe this will help: [MySQL 5.7 Reference Manual - B.5.3.2 How to Reset the Root Password](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/resetting-permissions.html).

Comment: @xander correct me if I'm wrong, but doesn't it all require to know the current root password ? (which precisely is the OP's problem)

Comment: @Rafalon Have you seen the link? I didn't try it myself but it should work without knowing the password. There is some explanation on that site under "B.5.3.2.2 Resetting the Root Password: Unix and Unix-Like Systems". I didn't want to copy it into an answer because it can simply be googled.

Comment: @xander Indeed, sorry it quite surprises me there's a way to log-in as root without knowing the password. I would consider this to be a flaw, but anyway if it's how it is designed ^^

Comment: @Rafalon It may be technically a flaw, but with most server systems there is just one file with all the passwords and if you have access to the service account or root/admin you can simply reset it usually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Stop the MySQL server process with the command **service mysql stop**
2. Start the MySQL server with the command **mysqld_safe —skip-grant-tables —skip-networking**
3. Connect to the MySQL server as the root user with the command **mysql -u root**
4. Exec the following MySQL commands to reset the root password:

mysql> use mysql;

​mysql> update user set authentication_string=password('NEWPASSWORD') where user='root';

​mysql> flush privileges;

​mysql> quit

Where NEWPASSWORD is the new password to be used.

Restart the MySQL daemon with the command **service mysql restart**. You should now be able to log into MySQL with the new password.

Comment: Isn't 3 a duplicate of 2 ? And how is he supposed to do 4 if he doesn't know his root password ?

Comment: Yeah, it's duplicated, sorry... Doing this, when you use mysql -u root, it doesn't ask you any password

Comment: I tried this, but while executing step no.2 i get the following error-

    2018-02-19T07:53:20.583914Z mysqld_safe Logging to syslog.
    2018-02-19T07:53:20.586925Z mysqld_safe Logging to 
    '/var/log/mysql/error.log'.
    2018-02-19T07:53:20.589731Z mysqld_safe Directory 
    '/var/run/mysqld' for UNIX socket file don't exists.

Comment: Try to create it: 

$ mkdir -p /var/run/mysqld
$ chown mysql:mysql /var/run/mysqld

Comment: @SharayuJadhav if it solved your problem, please mark this answer as accepted so people having the same problem can find it easily